# Removing ALL user object permissions form ACL / Folder structure

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0, powershell-4.0

I want to remove ALL AD User objects from a directory/folder security.

So, this maybe a stupid post and i appologise if it is...but basically i want to recurse through a directoery and remove all user objects from permissions.  Folder permissions should be secured using groups, buit occasionally there are user onjects directly being added to folders breaking the rules.  I've got a simple little script that works great for specific users, but i'm having trouble setting this to use a variable, eg all domain user accounts.  If i specify the $user variable as an AD search for instance it just doesnt work, eg $USER = 'Get-ADuser -filter * -Server 'DOMAIN -properties SamAccountName | Select SamAccountName

I'm assumign this doesnt like the variable field set this way.  Any help or advise much appreciated.  Thanks.

```
$filepath = 'C:\Temp\ACLTesting'
$user     = 'DOMAIN\USER'
Get-ChildItem $filePath -Recurse -Directory | ForEach-Object {
$acl = Get-Acl -Path $_.FullName

$acl.Access | Where-Object {
    $_.IdentityReference.Value -eq $user
} | ForEach-Object {
    $acl.RemoveAccessRule($_) | Out-Null
}

Set-Acl -Path $_.FullName -AclObject $acl
}
```

Unfortunately still cant get this to work using user variables... am i missing something or is this not a possible function?  Thanks....

---

Putting this to one side for now as still cant get it to work and other things have cropped up to look at.  Will revisit this at somepoint though.  Any suggestions always welcome.  Thanks.

Comment: If you are looking for ideas what to do then i would suggest looking into parsing the SDDL. You want to parse the SIDs from the SDDL and check them aginst AD. The AD object that is returned will tell you if its a group or not

Comment: Thanks for the advise.  I can determine what is a Group or user, but its getting the behaviour to work to remove only the users that i cant seem to make work, frustaring as i would have though this should be relatively easy to do.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Slightly modifying what you posted, try this …

```
$filepath = 'C:\Temp\ACLTesting'
$DomainUsers = (Get-ADUser -Filter *).SamAccountName

ForEach ($DomainUser in $DomainUsers)
{
    Get-ChildItem $filePath -Recurse -Directory | 
    ForEach-Object {
        $acl = Get-Acl -Path $_.FullName

        $acl.Access | 
        Where-Object {
            $_.IdentityReference.Value -eq $DomainUser
        } | 
        ForEach-Object {
            $acl.RemoveAccessRule($_) | Out-Null
        }

        Set-Acl -Path $_.FullName -AclObject $acl
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  Have tried this and it doesnt seem to work, ultimately runs through, no errors, but doesnt remove any user objects, not sure if it likes the ForEach and ForEach-Object of it.